# authData column isn't updated properly on Parse.com for Anonymous users

Tags: parse-platform

I'm creating anonymous users from an iOS application using this code:

```
[PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Anonymous login failed.");
    }   else
    {
        user.isAnonymous = true;
        NSLog(@"Anonymous user logged in.");
    }
}];
```

From time to time the authData column isn't populated with the "Anonymous" text and this means when I try to test if the user is anonymous it incorrectly reports that the user isn't anonymous. 
As far as I know the column should be populated automatically and I'm not really sure why this happens.

This is how it looks:(There are more even more intercalated)
[image]

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Thanks.